Erasure of method is the same as another method in type MyClass | two constructors with a List object with different object types
I try to create two constructors with List object parameters with different objects types but eclipse gives me the following error: Erasure of method is the same as another method in type MyClass.
import java.util.List;

public class MyClass {
    private List<String> stringList;
    private List<Integer> integerList;

    // Constructor with a list of strings
    public MyClass(List<String> stringList) {
        this.stringList = stringList;
    }

    // Constructor with a list of integers
    public MyClass(List<Integer> integerList) {
        this.integerList = integerList;
    }
}


How can I have two constructors with a List object with different object types or is this not possible?
